# set property with async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Can the various extension methods be changed to allow the FireAndForget call in the unit test below to be more elegant than I have it?

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace MyNamespace
{
  public static class AsyncAdditions
  {
    private static async Task FireAndForgetInternal<T>(Func<Task<T>> task, Action<T> completion) {
      T value = await task();
      completion(value);
    }

    public static void FireAndForget<T>(Func<Task<T>> task, Action<T> completion) {
      AsyncAdditions.FireAndForgetInternal(task, completion).DoNotAwait();
    }

    /// <summary>Empty method gets rid of stupid compiler warning</summary>
    public static void DoNotAwait(this Task task) {}
  }
}
```

the test:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;
using MyNamespace;

namespace MyTests
{
  [TestFixture()]
  public class AsyncTests
  {
    public async Task<int> GetAsyncInteger()
    {
      return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 6);
    }

    public int MyNumber { get; set;}

    public void SlowSynchronousJob() {
      for (int i = 0; i < 1E7; i++) {
      }
    }

    [Test()]
    public void TestSetter() {
      AsyncAdditions.FireAndForget(this.GetAsyncInteger, n => this.MyNumber = n);
      this.SlowSynchronousJob();
      Assert.AreEqual(6, this.MyNumber);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is why you should leverage the TPL instead of using a callback based model.  If you are given the `Task`, you can `await` it to ensure the remaining code runs after it has completed, which is exactly what you should be doing.  If you have code to run after the operation finishes, then you shouldn't be dropping the `Task` on the floor; clearly you still need it.

Comment: In a typical use case, the SlowSynchronousJob is actually waiting for some user input (and hence really is slow, and is not likely to complete before the async). When the user gives the input, I can just check if the result is there or not. If something utterly wild has happened and it isn't, I can handle that.

Comment: Waiting for user input is an inherently asynchronous operation, not a synchronous operation, so you shouldn't be doing that synchronously.  Next, why *go out of your way* to create a race condition.  Even if you think the "bad" result of the race condition is very unlikely, it would be *easier* to write the code correctly in such a way that it *can't* do the wrong thing.

Comment: That "stupid" compiler warning is there because ignoring tasks is almost always wrong, or at the very least leads to inelegant design problems. If you use the task appropriately instead of ignoring it, not only is your application code cleaner, but it's also much easier to unit test.